# If $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha \in \mathrm{End}(V)$ is a projection, show that $\mathrm{spec}(\alpha)\subseteq {0,1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $V$ is a vector space over  $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha \in \operatorname{End}(V)$ is a projection, show that $\operatorname{spec}(\alpha)\subseteq \{0,1\}$

The following is what I have so far, I am wondering if my process is correct.

Ok, so I know that $\operatorname{End}(V)$ is the set of all endomorphism.
So, suppose $\operatorname{spec}(\alpha)\subseteq \{0,1\}$, which is the set of all eigenvalues of $\alpha$.

Let's say that $c \in \operatorname{spec}(\alpha)$ iff $c\sigma_{1}$ of $V$ is not monic.

Using the fact that $\alpha \in \operatorname{End}(V)$ is a projection iff $\alpha^2=\alpha$, then 
$$Av=c\alpha v=c\alpha^2v=c\alpha^2v-c\alpha v=0=c\alpha(\alpha-1)v=0,
$$
$v\ne0$.

Therefore, $c=0$, $\alpha=0$, $\alpha=1$

Comment: For a proof that $\operatorname{spec}(\alpha)\in\{0,1\}$, you can hardly *suppose* in the beginning that $\operatorname{spec}(\alpha)\in\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is good, but there's a useless $A$ and moreover you should assume $v$ is an eigenvector to begin with. There are other flaws, first of all assuming that the spectrum is included in $\{0,1\}$. Finally, you can't conclude that $\alpha=0$ or $\alpha=1$.

If $c$ is an eigenvalue of $\alpha$, with an eigenvector $v$, then
$$
\alpha(v)=cv
$$
so $\alpha^2(v)=c^2v$. Therefore
$$
0=(\alpha^2-\alpha)(v)=\alpha^2(v)-\alpha(v)=c^2v-cv=(c^2-c)v
$$
Since $v\ne0$, we get $c^2-c=0$, so $c=0$ or $c=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea seems ok but you could simplify the proof by looking at the minimal polynomial.

By definition, a projection $\alpha$ is an endomorphism satisfying $\alpha^2=\alpha$. Cayley-Hamilton then implies that the minimal polynomial $m(\lambda)$ of $\alpha$ divides $\lambda^2-\lambda$. Hence the eigenvalues of $\alpha$ are either $0$ or $1$.